# Fstream getline() only reading from the very first line of text file, ignoring every other line

Tags: c++, fstream

I am working on a coding project where I sort and organize data from a text file, and I cannot get the getline() function to read past the first line.

The idea is to capture the entire line, split it into 3 sections, assign it to an object, then move on. I can do everything except get getline() to work properly, here is the snippet of code I am having trouble with:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("textFile.txt");
while (!fin.eof()) // while loop to grab lines until the end of file is reached
{
    getline(fin, line); 
    fin >> first >> last >> pace; // assigning the data to their respective variables
    ClassObject obj(first, last, pace); // creating an object with those variables
    ClassVector.push_back(obj); // assignment object to vector
}
```

This has been the closest I have gotten to reading every line while also sorting the data into a vector, but as I mentioned before, getline() will read line 1, and skip the rest of the file (1000 lines).

Comment: How are `first`, `last` and `pace` defined?

Comment: They are defined earlier in the code: string first, string last, int pace;

Comment: The first iteration of the `while` will read the first line with `getline`, and then the next `fin >>` will read those 3 variables, and probably finish the next line. The second `getline` will eat the leftover `\n`, and the `fin >>` will read the third line. Next, `getline` eats the leftover `\n` etc.

Comment: You're reading a `line` and then doing nothing with it. You then proceed to read `first`, `last` and `pace` _from the next line_. If that fails then the stream has an error and `eof` will return true, stopping the loop.

Comment: Okay, I see, how would I approach fixing this? I am unsure how to capture the first, last, and pace sections of each line otherwise

Comment: I got it now!! Thank you guys so much! This has been such a headache to deal with, and for such a simple solution.

Comment: issue 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/1387438

Comment: issue 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567292/1387438

Comment: In summary: ditch the `eof` check (there's a failr chance that you will never find a good use for `eof` in your entire career) and write `while (fin >> first >> last >> pace) { ... }`.

Comment: if you use a debugger you might find the problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is rather than using `!fin.eof()`. i prefer to use something similar to this:

```
    ifstream file ( fileName.c_str() );

    while (file >> first >> last >> pace ) // assuming the file is delimited with spaces
    {
        // Do whatever you want with first, last, and pace
    }
```

The "While loop" will keep reading the next line until we reach the end of the file.

If the lengths of *first, last, pace* are constant, you can also just get the contents of the line (in a string variable) and use substring on it, but this only works in the specific case that the lengths are constant throughout the entire file.